# Connect Windows 7 to DP-300U (with attached HP 722C Printer)

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-adapter, network-printer

I'm trying to add a new printer to Windows 7, but it cannot find it.  My printer is an HP 722C attached to a DLink DP-300U network adapter.  I enter the ip address of the network adapter, but Windows 7 does not recognize the printer.

Any advice to get this working?

Comment: Oh, as a side note, my laptop running XP can connect fine to the printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 Release recognizes the printer if you do Windows Update and select Deskjet 720c.

For 64 bit versions of Windows7, you'll need to install a patch.  Patch instructions are as follows:

1. First make sure the driver for the printer is installed.
2. Log into the computer with an administrative account.
3. Download the patch from [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/attachments/psg/Software/9371/1/DJ_Patch.zip) and unzip the patch to a temp location
4. Copy the three DLL files to the following directory: %windir%\system32\spool\drivers\x64\3

More info is available from HP at [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software-and/Deskjet-710-720-810-820-100-Series-printers-Patch-for-64-bit/m-p/203377#U203377).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of vista you could try copying the %systemroot%\inf and %systemroot%\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository folder to the windows 7 box, add the filerepository to the path, run the add printer wizard and when it asks you for drivers point it to the vista INF directory.

if that doesn't work...

If you have a backup of your system you can also just try copying those folders to the same ones in windows 7. It's s longshot but in theory it should work.